# Extract string values that are enclosed in slashes

Tags: google-sheets

An example url that I'm trying to collect the values from has this pattern:

```
https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/08/18/canada/canadian-championship/hfx-wanderers/blainville/3576866/
```

The searched value always starts at the seventh `/` and ends at the ninth `/`:

```
/canada/canadian-championship/
```

The method I know how to do is using `LEFT` + `FIND` and `RIGHT` + `FIND`, but it is very archaic, I believe there is a better method for this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The searched value always starts at the seventh `/` and ends at the ninth `/`:

Here's another way you can do it:

```
="/"&regexextract(A1,"(?:.*?/){7}(.*?/.*?/)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
="/"&textjoin("/", 1, query(split(A1, "/"), "Select Col7, Col8"))&"/"
```

Comment: Interesting... I don't event think query can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use =REGEXTRACT() to match part of the string with a regular expression:

For example, If A1 = `https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2021/08/18/canada/canadian-championship/hfx-wanderers/blainville/3576866/` ,
then

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/)")
```

returns
`/canada/canadian-championship/`

Explanation: `\/` is `'/'` escaped. `[^\/]*` matches any non `'/'` character 0 or more times. `\/[^\/]*` is repeated 6 times. `()` captures a specific part of the string as a group to be returned. Finally `(\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/)` matches the essential part we want.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit different approach.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",9),"/","|",7),"\|(.*?)\|")
```

[image]